# Launch IE with script debugging turned on

Tags: internet-explorer

Is there a command line parameter or something for IE10 that launches IE with the developer tools open and script debugging turned on?  It's so annoying to have to hit F12 and then click debugging on.

Comment: Haha, I'm not crazy enough to try to develop on Windows 8.  I'm using Windows 7 with IE10.

Comment: Wow, so no one has an answer?  You'd think MS would have made this possible by now.

Comment: tbh I doubt. You can fiddle around with things in options which won't help at all; but if there's a solution that must be "workaround" IMHO. ie. start from ruby/vbs/etc and send the keys to enable debugging to the browser window when (if ever) it's loaded - or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

No Such methods, Unfortunately. However, [a list of available options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and a [reference guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). which you might already know